# ReactJS. Конкатенация элементов JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Есть два элемента:

```
elem1 = <div>1</div>;
elem2 = <div>2</div>;
```

Существует ли способ их конкатенировать в другую переменную **newElem**, чтобы при

```
ReactDOM.render(newElem, ...)
```

отображался результат склейки elem1 и elem2?
Ожидаю увидеть `<div>1</div><div>2</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого <strike>можно</strike> нужно использовать React.Fragment

```
let elem1 = <div>1</div>;
let elem2 = <div>2</div>;
ReactDOM.render(<>{elem1}{elem2}</>, rootEement);
```

Или его более чистую запись:

```
let elem1PlusElem2 = React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, elem1, elem2);
ReactDOM.render(elem1PlusElem2);
```

**Всегда должен быть 1 элемент root уровня, даже если это невидимка.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elem1 = '<div>1</div>';
let elem2 = '<div>2</div>';
let newElem = elem1 + elem2;
console.log(newElem);
```

Comment: [Object] + [Object] ? Это что-то новенькое ))))

Comment: @EugeneX Извиняюсь. В примере я строку написал, не объект) а в задачке про объекты... глупость написал, получается